# How do I consume WCF services in SQL / SQL CLR?

Tags: c#, wcf, sql-server-2008-r2, sqlclr

How do I consume WCF services in SQL / SQL CLR?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Please provide more information on your use case.

Comment: @Mutant I need to consume sms service witten in WCF from sqlserver using Managed Code Stored Procedure

Comment: my knowledge is limited in that area :) however, not sure if you come across this - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/b8033f21-acf2-45cc-9b16-ea277bebf6ce or http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saradhic/archive/2007/09/12/invoke-wcf-service-via-sql.aspx

Comment: @Mutant Thanks for quick reply with  good links.

Answer (score 3):

I actually implemented just this very thing for a query integration problem recently at work.

You can create the SQLCLR project in Visual Studio and then simply create your WCF Service reference as normal.  Once you have that you can invoke the service client methods within your [SqlFunction] or [SqlProcedure] attributed SQLCLR function.

There are two main gotchas to watch out for: [1] WCF endpoint configuration has to be done programmatically since no web service app.config file can be read for the managed SQLCLR assembly, as invocation is from within SqlServer.exe.  [2] You may need to Gacutil some assemblies from .NET 3.0, if calling the SQLCLR function or sproc from SQL Server 2008 or below.  Those assemblies in question for me were:

C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\System.IdentityModel.dll
C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\System.IdentityModel.Selectors.dll

Good luck, hope this helps!